# How to count cells with specific text & color

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to count cells with specific color and text in Google Sheets.
I found a code for counting cells with color, here it is

```
function countColor(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();  
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var countCells = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        countCells = countCells + 1;
  return countCells;
};
```

So the formula in Google Sheets looks like this :

```
=countcolor(Sheet1!A:A,C1)
```

where `A:A1` is range and `C1` is a cell with color sample

A friend of mine helped me a bit and made a function to count text & color, but the text should be typed inside of the function.
Here is the code:

```
function count_Color_and_text_Cells(countRange,colorRef) { 
var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); 
var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula(); 
var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim(); 
var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds(); 
var text = "test" // Text you whant to count
var arrData = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getDisplayValues() 
var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim(); 
var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground(); 
var countCells = 0; 
for (var row = 0; row < backGrounds.length; row++) 
for (var col = 0; col < backGrounds[row].length; col++) 
if ( backGrounds[row][col] == BackGround ) 
if (arrData[row][col].match(text)) 
countCells = countCells + 1; 
return countCells; 

}
```

What I need is to make text criteria in function so i can choose a range, type a specific text and get the result. Expecting it looks like this:

```
=countcolor(Sheet1!A:A,"TextSample",C1)
```

So it could count cells with proper color and text typed by user in a formula.

Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: Add `text` as a accepted argument to that function?

Comment: @TheMaster can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide text as a argument like this:

```
function count_Color_and_text_Cells(countRange,text,colorRef) {
```

Don't declare `text` again i.e., remove `var text=''`

#### To Read and practice:

- [Javascript functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)